# Best way to Sign in to Twitter with Django

Tags: python, django, twitter

I use these 3 ways to login twitter on django, but not successful now:

1. Django-SocialAuth
2. django-twitterauth
3. http://hameedullah.com/step-by-step-guide-to-use-sign-in-with-twitter-with-django.html

I'm tired with it, so are there any other ways to sign in to Twitter with Django.

Comment: what issue did you get while using the mentioned apps?

Comment: i cant get the access_token .

Answer (score 2):

I've recently been using this for a project. Its pretty good.

https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython-django

Answer (score 2):

I recently used [Django Social Registration](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) and liked it a lot. It also handles other oauth, oauth2, and openid services.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is "Best way to sign in to Django with Twitter" and not the other way around? Put a bit broader, your question is basically of the form "Best way to sign in to Django with (insert-favorite-social-network)", one version of which is discussed over here:

[A simple and up-to-date way to implement Facebook login in a Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220952/a-simple-and-up-to-date-way-to-implement-facebook-login-in-a-django-app/12227316)

Btw, `allauth` stores the access token for you. Check here how it can be used to post a tweet:

[How to status update on twitter in django with Oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231043/how-to-status-update-on-twitter-in-django-with-oauth/12231273#12231273)