# How can I get the user's facebook id with django-allauth?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I want to display a picture of the current_user in my template. How can I access the user's facebook id when I'm using django-allauth?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For each user that is signed up via a social account a `SocialAccount` instance is available. This model has a foreign key to `User`. Note that a user can connect multiple social networking accounts to his local account, so in practice there may be more than one `SocialAccount` instances available.

How you want to deal with this is project dependent. I can imagine one would want to copy the profile image locally, or perhaps you would want to give preference to the Google+ profile picture above the Facebook one, and so on.

The `SocialAccount` model has some helper methods that give you access to account basics such as the profile picture. All in all, this is a quick & dirty way to access first available profile picture:

```
{{user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url}}
```

The ID is also available:

```
{{user.socialaccount_set.all.0.uid}}
```

See also: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/models.py#L72

Comment: Is it possible to get linkedin professional headline and twitter profile Bio information?