# How to acces the connected user's socialaccount in django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

In [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222021/how-can-i-get-the-users-facebook-id-with-django-allauth)'s answer, it is mentionned that a user can have several social accounts linked, and how to access all of them (or the first one).

However, how could I access (or find) the precise one the user is logged in with ? (I'd like to show them "you're connected with ...").

Comment: I just realized that I could do: socialaccount_set.order_by('-last_login')[0].
However, aside from feeling clumsy (compared to an hypothetic clean get_account method), this could be incorrect, in case a user is logged in with several user agents/devices at the same time.

Comment: I found that solution too, using a signal handler to attach data to the session:

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged_in(request, user, **kwargs):
    if 'sociallogin' in kwargs:
        account = kwargs['sociallogin'].account
        request.session['socialaccount'] = account

This one is probably more correct, but still feels like I'm hacking to implement something that should already exist.

Comment: I was about to suggest you using signals.