# How to status update on twitter in django with Oauth

Tags: python, django, twitter, oauth-2.0

I added my web site twitter login thanks to omab's social_auth project. It works well.

But I want make the authenticated users share twits on my web site possible .

How can I do this requirement?

Any helps and  ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about `social_auth`, but `django-allauth` stores (and updates) the token on each login, over at:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/models.py#L82

Then it is simply a matter of feeding that token to e.g. `Tweepy` (http://tweepy.github.com) in order to post a tweet on behalf of the user.

Comment: assuming that I was using allauth, how can i feed tweepy ?? any example??

Comment: Something like this:

import tweepy; auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret); auth.set_access_token(socialtoken.token, socialtoken.token_secret); api = tweepy.API(auth); api.update_status('Hello world')

Comment: How can I get social token from your provider ? Could you give an example please?