# Using Django's registration and login with Django-allauth

Tags: django

I've been trying to add a functionality to my app, so that uses can push the posts they create on my website to there Facebook, Twitter and G+ profiles.

So I decided [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) can be a good way to go about it. But what I want is users to Register and Login using Django's Authentication backend and once they are in the system then they can choose to Link their FB, Twitter and G+ profiles.

Is there a way to achieve this kind of functionality using django-allauth?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to restrict users to sign up using only a local account (username/e-mail based). Then, once signed up, they would be allowed to link social accounts. Right?  I am not sure what the advantage of that approach would be. django-allauth, out of the box, offers signup using any which way the user wants. Whichever way (s)he decides to signup, there will always be a regular Django account created to which the social login is attached. If you insist, you can prevent a social signup without having created a local account by adding this logic in a custom adapter..

Comment: oh okay! I wasn't aware of that! So what you are saying is that I can use login with FB, Twitter, G+ and at the same time have my own custom login as well? so the user can choose which one they want to login / Signup with?

Comment: Exactly -- have a look at the list of example sites to get a feel of how this works (bottom of the README, over at https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth)

Comment: Yeah I had a look at them. I should've done that before. I just got intimidated. Also, does Django-allauth give an out of the box posting stuff functionality? or would I have to build it individually for FB, Twitter and G+?

Comment: allauth stores the access tokens for you such that you can easily start posting etc. However, it does not, and will not, include posting functionality -- allauth is meant for authentication and just that. For an example of how to post a tweet, see the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231043/how-to-status-update-on-twitter-in-django-with-oauth/12231273#12231273

Comment: okay. Well I would definitely install all this tonight and see how it goes. I might bug you again if I run into any issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Given our comment discussion above, your original question was not what you were really after.

Still to provide an answer to that original question, provided someone else is interested: `allauth` now (*) supports an `is_open_for_signup(self, request, sociallogin)` method that you can override. It lives on the DefaultSocialAccountAdapter. Simply return false here to disable social signups.

(*) since https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/commit/6794afedcdeaafa907f1184772371f44e742514f