# Override is_open_for_signup in Django

Tags: django

[Using Django's registration and login with Django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779621/using-djangos-registration-and-login-with-django-allauth)

How does one override this module in Django? Can someone help me understand how to get started accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inerit you class from `DefaultSocialAccountAdapter`.
Then, specify it in `SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER` setting.

Check https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/docs/configuration.rst for details